# Difference of ImageHistogram and Histogram of gray scale image

Tags: image-processing, histograms

I have a gray scale image showing noise and would like to plot the histogram.

The image is:

[image]

A. When I use `ImageHistogram` I get the histogram with:

```
ImageHistogram[image, 256, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.05}, All}]
```

B. Compared to that the function `Histogram` looks slightly different when I use the data of the image. What is the reason, that the bins start and end at different positions?

```
data = Flatten@ImageData[image];
Histogram[data, 256, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.05}, All}]
```

[image]

Comment: If you specify the bin size explicitly, like so: `Histogram[data, {1/255}]`, you get exactly the same histogram. `Histogram[data ,256` uses exactly 256 bins, but without specifying the range, `Histogram` can place the bins anywhere.

Comment: note using `PlotRange` does not affect the data range used for the bin determination. If you want to manually control the bin range you should actually use the *bspec* `{min, max,dx}` form

Comment: @nikie and george2079: Thank you for your help.