# Gray level shading of image histogram bins

Tags: image-processing, image, histograms, filling

## How to shade bins in an `ImageHistogram` to match the image `GrayLevel`?

### Inputs

Import the following graphic:

[image: gray level image]

```
B = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Fxc.png"];
```

Create a histogram of the pixel intensities:

```
ImageHistogram[B]
```

The output is

[image]

### How to shade the histogram bins to match the image?

The goal is to shade the bins to match the image. For example, if the bin counts the number of pixels with `GrayLevel`s between `0.09` and `0.1`, the bin would be `GrayLevel[0.09]`

### Attempts

[`ImageHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageHistogram.html?q=ImageHistogram) provides controls for [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html), yet I am unable to exploit [`FillingStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FillingStyle.html).

While I can shade a graphics primitive using [`LinearGradientFilling[{Black, White}]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearGradientFilling.html?q=LinearGradientFilling) (below), it was not clear how to apply this in `ImageHistogram`.

[image: gradient shadind]

Investigated, without luck, this post: [Histograms of grayscale images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104164/histograms-of-gray-scale-images) and this post [Difference of ImageHistogram and Histogram of grayscale image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126858/difference-of-imagehistogram-and-histogram-of-gray-scale-image)

Comment: I was trying `ImageHistogram[B,6,ColorFunction->(GrayLevel[Floor[#,1/5]]&)]`, but it doesn't work -- the color is a gradient and not choppy as I desire!

Comment: But `ImageHistogram` [_does_ support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z5rL.png) `FillingStyle`! Which version are you using?

Comment: @Domen. You are correct. Thanks for catching that. (Using v 13.2)

Answer (score 5):

```
B = RandomImage[1, {200, 200}];
ImageHistogram[B, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]

With your image we have to scale the vertical axis to see anything. For example, with logarithmic scaling of the vertical axis:

```
B = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Fxc.png"];
ImageHistogram[B, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
               ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Do it yourself using a bar chart:

```
B = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Fxc.png"];
binned = ImageLevels[B, 256];
BarChart[binned[[All, 2]], ChartStyle -> (GrayLevel@*First /@ binned), PlotRange -> {0, 500}]
```

[image: histogram of image gray levels]

Comment: If you reduce the number of bins (currently 256) you'll be able to see that this doesn't produce a gradient but each bar has its own colour, as desired.